# Give user an option to choose whether to use lightbox or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm building simple web gallery and I want to leave on user whether to open image in Lightbox or to open full image (in new tab).

This should be done by simple button "Use Lightbox (yes/no)".
I presume this could be done with jQuery, but not sure how....

Thanks for help!

Comment: @AlienArrays - yes, definitely (it is mainly for people from IT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know if the user has changed the checkbox...like if he turn it on or not. For example (jquery):

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {...});
```

So, every time he changes the state of the checkbox input the function is run. In this function, check whether the checkbox is selected by getting a boolean from:

```
$('#checkbox1').prop("checked").
```

Now you can change all the things in the links, that the lightbox want. You can do it by using the attr function = $('#link1').attr("attr-name","val).

If the checkbox is not selected, remove the attributes of the lightbox (input.removeAttr( "title")) and add the target="_blank" attribute.